# How to get page_fan_adds using PHP SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

thanks in advance (Sorry my english is very poor)

I am learning about Graph API in facebook and PHP SDK. I am trying get all new fans in my fan pages. So I made the follow:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
require "sdk/src/Facebook/autoload.php";
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXX',
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
]);
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX');


    $date_start = "2016-04-03";
    $date_end = "2016-04-05";
    $date_start = strtotime($date_start."+ 1 day");
    $date_end = strtotime($date_end."+ 2 days");

$consulta = '256259981140982/insights/page_fan_adds?since='.$date_start.'&until='.$date_end;
$query = $fb->get($consulta);
$response = $query->getGraphEdge();
echo $consulta;

echo "<hr>";
foreach ($response as $day) {
    $dayX = $day->asArray();
    foreach ($dayX['values'] as $currentDay) {
        echo $currentDay['value'] . '<br>';
    }   
}
?>
```

My question:

there are some method to get the value for page_fan_adds in each day.

Comment: Sorry I meant, one method to get this information more easily. For example without have to use foreach?

Comment: Why, what’s wrong with foreach? If you don’t have a single value, but an _array_ of values, then you will want to loop over that array in one way or another, to get the individual entries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I thought maybe exist a better form. For example, when my date interval is only one day. I thought should exist one method. i don't get understand why I have to use toArray function. there are other form to get this information?

Comment: No, it is important that such an API response is always in the same format. You might be specifically requesting data here that results in only one “record” – but imagine other situations, where a developer might not know beforehand, if the response will contain only one, or more records. If the return was _not_ always an array, one would need to implement a check for that every single time – whereas if always an array is returned, you just loop over the result, and don’t have to bother whether that loop will run only one, two or 37 times.

Comment: Ok, always should use toArray function? how to can mark the question how accepted or solved?